# Bluetooth permission request dialog - recreated on screen rotation(orientation change)

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-alertdialog, device-orientation

I have used the following code for enabling Bluetooth ([as described here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)) and the same runs in onCreate() of the launcher activity of my app -

```
Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 101);
```

Now the problem is when this dialog is popped up, then every time i rotate the device, the dialog gets created again again on top of the previously created dialog.

I am preventing my activity from getting recreated by handling it from manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

This doesn't occur in all devices
I am getting this on :
LG Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy Grand

And not on :
Samsung I9500 Galaxy S4

Edit :
Found this Reported Issue but couldn't find the solution
[Here is the link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60002&can=1&q=Dialog%20for%20requesting%20user%20permission%20to%20enable%20Bluetooth&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

Created another issue [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219105)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this bug was never solved !!
I have tested this on several devices including latest [Pixel device](https://madeby.google.com/intl/en_in/phone/) and it still exists
And the same has been raised several time on [code.google.com/p/android](https://code.google.com/p/android/)


Reference to raised issues :
[Issue 60002:   Bluetooth permission request dialog](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60002&can=1&q=Dialog%20for%20requesting%20user%20permission%20to%20enable%20Bluetooth&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)
[Issue 219105 On each rotation, dialog for requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth, the request dialog is placed on the top of the stack](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219105)
[Issue 24931:   Bluetooth permission request dialog - recreated on screen rotation(orientation change)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24931)

**In case anyone finds a solution then please do post it here**

Answer (score 0):

When we rotated device its configration change method is call in activity.
You just need to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity element in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivty"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

I hope it will help you to solve the problem

Comment: I have handled the configuration changes in "onConfigurationChanged". So i don't think this will help !

Comment: The dialog which is created again and again is in onResume() function or in any other function

Comment: Since my activity is not getting recreated so onResume() or onCreate() which holds the code for dialog creation is not getting called again on device rotation..